# Address super Regex

Tags: c#, regex, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a regex that can capture an address in many forms. It all works perfectly until I try to code the possibility that the suburb may have more than one word in it.

Here' what I get at the moment:

```
Input:
"Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville vic 3070"
Output Groups:
PropertyType = "Unit"
Unit = "1"
Number = "61"
Street = "bob-bob east"
Street Type = "st"
Suburb = "bobville"
State = "VIC"
Postcode = "3070"

Input:
"Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville west vic 3070"
Output Groups:
PropertyType = "Unit"
Unit = "1"
Number = "61"
Street = "bob-bob east"
Street Type = "st"
Suburb = "bobville"
State = ""
Postcode = ""
```

And here's the regex:

```
new MyRegex("Address2", @"((?<PropertyType>Unit|Lot|Level|Floor|P.?O.? Box)\b)?" +
@"\s*((?<Unit>\d+)(/|\\|-| ))?" +
@"\s*(?<Number>\d+)" +
@"\s*(?<Street>[a-z]+((\s*|-?)[a-z]+)*?)" +
@"\s*(?<StreetType>st|rd|ave|hwy|cct|ct|cl|gr|street|road|avenue|highway|circuit|court|close|grove)\.?" +
@"\s*(?<Suburb>[a-z]+((\s*|-?)[a-z]+)*?)?" +
@"\s*(?<State>Victoria|Tasmania|Queensland|New South Wales|(South|Western) Australia|(Northern|Australian Capital) Territory|VIC|NSW|SA|WA|NT|TAS|ACT|QLD)?" +
@"\s*(?<Postcode>\d{4})?"
, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
```

Replacing the Suburb line with:

```
\s*(?<Suburb>[a-z]+(((\s*|-?)[a-z]+){1,2}?)?)?
```

Will capture "Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville west vic 3070" properly, but "Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville-bob west vic 3070" won't.

Similarly replacing the Suburb line with:

```
\s*(?<Suburb>[a-z]+(((\s*|-?)[a-z]+){1,2})?)?
```

Will capture "Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville-east west vic 3070", but not "Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville west vic 3070".

Replacing the Suburb line with:

```
\s*(?<Suburb>[a-z]+((\s*|-?)[a-z]+){0,2}?)?
```

Doesn't like anything except "Unit 1/61 bob-bob east st. bobville vic 3070". Changing {0,2}? to {0,2}, then also captures the state in the suburb line.

Any ideas on how I could clean this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a much quicker address regex, that also fails in a timely manner. It's based on this regex:
[www.regexlib.com](http://www.regexlib.com/(X(1)A(9G629Od0C_leQbarwdjlDrnLM55_pYilUukGZ8K0mh1_LmKQQ8HF2uRHeaw6PhD-Tn9sWL6j-fE_qqCOCCqVGq4kbhKAxe8B0jVlgv8Ssi5grSNyHSbjwVJfKI7wDYY0ub7O6COtE3pVZzKWv7EoqmhrknPbt4f8AEsCEZMosxDlRQY1VNIQfzep-1-4LKOE0))/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=4844)

I thought id post it in case someone needed something similar down the track:

```
new Regex(@"
^(
    ((?<PropertyType>[a-z\ ,\.']+?)\ *?)?
    ((?<Unit>\d+)(,|/|-|[\ ]*?))?
    (\b(?<Number>\d+[a-z]?)\b)\ *?
    (?<Street>[\w\ '-]+)
    (\b(?<StreetType>STREET|ST|ROAD|RD|GROVE|GR|DRIVE|DR|AVENUE|AVE|CIRCUIT|CCT|CLOSE|CL|COURT|CRT|CT|CRESCENT|CRES|PLACE|PL|PARADE|PDE|BOULEVARD|BLVD|HIGHWAY|HWY|ALLEY|ALLY|APPROACH|APP|ARCADE|ARC|BROW|BYPASS|BYPA|CAUSEWAY|CWAY|CIRCUS|CIRC|COPSE|CPSE|CORNER|CNR|COVE|END|ESPLANANDE|ESP|FLAT|FREEWAY|FWAY|FRONTAGE|FRNT|GARDENS|GDNS|GLADE|GLD|GLEN|GREEN|GRN|HEIGHTS|HTS|LANE|LINK|LOOP|MALL|MEWS|PACKET|PCKT|PARK|PARKWAY|PKWY|PROMENADE|PROM|RESERVE|RES|RIDGE|RDGE|RISE|ROW|SQUARE|SQ|STRIP|STRP|TARN|TERRACE|TCE|THOROUGHFARE|TFRE|TRACK|TRAC|TRUNKWAY|TWAY|VIEW|VISTA|VSTA|WALK|WAY|WALKWAY|WWAY|YARD)\b).?,?\ *?
 )
 ((?<Suburb>[a-z'.]+([\-,\ ]+[a-z'.]+)*?),?\ *?)?
 (\b(?<State>New\ South\ Wales|NSW|Victoria|VIC|Queensland|QLD|Australian\ Capital\ Territory|ACT|South\ Australia|SA|West\ Australia|WA|Tasmania|TAS|Northern\ Territory|NT)\b,?\ *?)?
 ((?<Postcode>\d{4}),?\ *?)?
 (Au(s(tralia)?)?)?
 (\s(?=[^$]))* 
$"
, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | 
  RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture |
  RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```